# Redux using Native React error type error: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.counter')

Tags: react-native, redux

I am trying to use redux with react native, followed the example in your tube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KcC8KZ_Ga2M

This is a very simple counter app with minimal coding

It keeps giving me this error, i've tried this multiple times but could not figure out what keeps throwing the error.

> "error type error: undefined is not an object (evaluating
> '_this.props.counter') This error is located at: in CounterApp
> (created by ConnectFunction) "

This is my app.js code below

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import CounterApp from './src/CounterApp'

import {createStore} from 'redux'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'

const initialState = {
  counter: 0
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type)
  {
    case 'INCREASE_COUNTER':
      return {counter: state.counter+1}
    case 'DECREASE_COUNTER': 
      return {counter: state.counter-1}
  }
  return state 
}

const store = createStore(reducer)

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <CounterApp/>
    </Provider>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

And my CounterApp.js code below

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

const CounterApp = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', width: 200, justifyContent: 'space-around'}}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.props.increaseCounter()}>
          <Text>Increase</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text>{this.props.counter}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.props.decreaseCounter()}>
          <Text>Decrease</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return{
        counter: state.counter
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return{
        increaseCounter : () => dispatch({type: 'INCREASE_COUNTER'}),
        decreaseCounter : () => dispatch({type: 'DECREASE_COUNTER'})
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CounterApp)

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Please help i've bee struggling with this for weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access to `this` of your function component especially the arrow function as well. The `props` is the argument of your `CounterApp` component instead. Then your component would look like:

```js
const CounterApp = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', width: 200, justifyContent: 'space-around'}}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.increaseCounter()}>
          <Text>Increase</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text>{props.counter}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.decreaseCounter()}>
          <Text>Decrease</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```